NestJS Sequelize stop syncing when another sync on another object is startet
I am trying to manage multiple Sequelize connections in a nestjs server.
I have to create a DB per client. If a client wants a connection, I check a map, if not there I create a new Seuqlize object, sync it and store the connection in said map for future needs.
Now I tried a mass test with first 100, then 10 different clients requesting in an not awaited loop to make i as . The MySQL-Server allows 150 connctions.
The Idea is a client (defined by the clientDomain) request DB access over getDB(), checks the list, and if there is no Sequelize object for the client, calls addDB() which will call createDB() to make shure the database does exist. Then establishes a connection, syncs the datamodels, add to the list and returns.
So far, the plan.
If there is only one client request at once, there are no errors or problems.
My theory for now is that when a Sequelize.sync() is running and another Sequelize.sync() on another Sequelize instance is startet it interupts the first one. I have no Idea how or even if that works but that my I asume this, since the last test runs throw without problems.
With my test of 100 requests it will create the Sequelize object, but while it is in the sync it trows an exception for each Database but the last:
2024-05-30T09:38:50.170Z [error] [Logger] Table 'client-8_testDB.ChangeLogs' doesn't exist
Error:
    at Query.run ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\mysql\query.js:46:25)
    at [ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:650:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at MySQLQueryInterface.showIndex ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:600:12)
    at Function.sync ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1413:29)
    at Sequelize.sync ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:825:9)
    at DatabaseService.addDB ([ProjectPath]\server\src\modules\database\database.service.ts:83:4)
    at DatabaseService.getDB ([ProjectPath]\server\src\modules\database\database.service.ts:116:15)
    at DatabaseService.getUserRepository ([ProjectPath]\server\src\modules\database\database.service.ts:301:11)
    at AuthController.test ([ProjectPath]\server\src\modules\auth\auth.controller.ts:22:3)


With my test of 10 requests it will create the Sequelize object but while it is in the sync it trows this exception for each request but the last:
2024-05-30T09:31:44.203Z [error] [Logger] DB Exception-------------------------------- 

2024-05-30T09:31:44.283Z [error] [Logger] Unknown database 'client-10_testDB' 
SequelizeConnectionError: Unknown database 'client-10_testDB'
    at ConnectionManager.connect ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:126:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at ConnectionManager._connect ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:332:24)
    at [ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
    at ConnectionManager.getConnection ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
    at [ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:638:26
    at MySQLQueryInterface.dropTable ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:265:5)
    at Function.drop ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1448:12)
    at Sequelize.drop ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:927:9)
    at Sequelize.sync ([ProjectPath]\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:807:7)
2024-05-30T09:31:44.284Z [error] [Logger] ------------------------------------------

MyCode
    @Injectable()
    export class DatabaseService{
        private list = new Map<string, Sequelize>();
        async getDB(clientDomain): Promise<Sequelize> {
            const cd = clientDomain;    
            if (this.list.has(cd)) {
                //this.dbInWaiting.delete(clientDomain);
                return this.list.get(cd);
            } else {
                const db = await this.addDB(cd);
                //this.dbInWaiting.delete(clientDomain);
                return db;
            }
        }

        
        async addDB(clientDomain): Promise<Sequelize> {
            let seq: Sequelize;
            try {
                const dbName = clientDomain + '_' + this.configService.database.db_name;
                await this.createDB(dbName);
                seq = new Sequelize({
                    dialect: DB_DIALECT,
                    dialectOptions: {
                        decimalNumbers: true,
                    },
                    host: this.configService.database.host,
                    port: this.configService.database.port,
                    username: this.configService.database.user,
                    password: this.configService.database.password,
                    database: dbName,
                    models: DB_MODELS,
                    logging: console.log,
                    pool: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 1,
                    },
                });
                await seq.sync({
                    force: true,
                });
                this.logger.log(dbName + ' synced');
                this.list.set(clientDomain, seq);
                return seq;
            } catch (e) {
                if (seq) {
                    await seq.close();
                }
                this.logger.error('DB Exception--------------------------------');
                this.logger.error(e);
                this.logger.error('-------------------------------------------');
                throw e;
            }
        }

        async createDB(clientDomain: string): Promise<boolean> {
            if (clientDomain == undefined || clientDomain == 'undefined') {
                throw new BadRequestException(CLIENT_DOMAIN_HEADER_NAME + ' is not set');
            }
            let sequelize: Sequelize;
            try {
                sequelize = new Sequelize({
                    dialect: DB_DIALECT,
                    host: this.configService.database.host,
                    port: this.configService.database.port,
                    username: this.configService.database.user,
                    password: this.configService.database.password,
                    models: DB_MODELS,
                    logging: console.log,
                    logQueryParameters: true,
                });
                await sequelize.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `' + clientDomain + '`');
                await sequelize.close();
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                if (sequelize) {
                    await sequelize.close();
                }
                this.logger.error(`error while creating database: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

